Additivity of outer measure
This question is from Frank Jones, Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Spaces.
I have to show that in general,
$\lambda^*(A) + \lambda^*(B) \geq \lambda^*(A \cup B) + \lambda^*(A\cap B)$.
My idea was to use the fact that $A\cup B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \cup (A \cap B) $ .
Then by property of outer measure, we have
$\lambda^*(A\cup B) \leq \lambda^*(A \setminus B) + \lambda^*(B \setminus A) + \lambda^*(A \cap B) $ and consequently
$\lambda^*(A\cup B) + \lambda^*(A\cap B) \leq \lambda^*(A \setminus B) + \lambda^*(B \setminus A) + 2\lambda^*(A \cap B) $ .
But I am stuck here.
I do know that for the RHS the union of $A \setminus B$ and $A \cap B$ are A and the union of the remainder becomes B, but it seems that then  $\lambda^*(A \setminus B) + \lambda^*(B \setminus A) + 2\lambda^*(A \cap B) \geq \lambda^*(A) +  \lambda^*(B)$, making it impossible to prove the original statement.
I would appreciate some help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
